# asp mvc - generic repository and unit of work - override repository method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am new to repository patterns in ASP MVC 2 and I am trying to figure out how to extend an operation in my generic repository class, and am having trouble figuring out how do it or find examples of it online.  I want a generic repository and unit of work that will work for most cases, but want something easy to alter slightly for special cases.

I have the following generic repository interface and repository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    List<TEntity> Get();
    TEntity GetByKey(object key);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Save();
}

public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly string entity_set_name;
    public readonly string entity_key_name;

    private ObjectContext object_context;
    private ObjectSet<TEntity> object_set;

    public RepositoryBase(ObjectContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        object_context = context;
        object_set = object_context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();

        entity_set_name = object_set.EntitySet.Name;
        entity_key_name = object_set.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Single().Name;
    }

    public virtual List<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return object_set.ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByKey(object key)
    {
        var entityKey = new EntityKey(entity_set_name, entity_key_name, key);
        return (TEntity)object_context.GetObjectByKey(entityKey);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        object_set.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        object_set.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        object_context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

...and the following Unit of Work class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private MyEntities context = null;
    public Dictionary<Type, object> repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        context = new EmployeeAccessFormEntities();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)) == true)
        {
            return repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IRepository<TEntity>;
        }
        IRepository<TEntity> r = new RepositoryBase<TEntity>(context);
        repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), r);
        return r;
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have a specific type of entity that needs additional work added to the insert method.  I want to do someting like:

```
public partial class MyEntity : RepositoryBase<MyEntity>
{
    public override void Insert(MyEntity entity)
    {
        // do additional work

        base.Insert(entity);
    }
}
```

...but I receive an error that "Partial declarations must not specify different base classes."

So my question is, where would I be able to put that overridden Insert method?  Do I have to make a seperate repository that inherits the generic repository?  If I did that, how would I need to change my unit of work class?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Why you guys are still trying to discover a wheel. Entity Framework context already implements these 2 patterns. What else do you need? What is a purpose of this additional abstraction?

Comment: There is only one repository pattern, that has nothing to do with  language or framework as it's a principle (it's unrelated to a certain implementation). As long as your business layer works with a repository getting/saving business objects it's the repository pattern. The code implementation is specific to each app.

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich While EF implements UoW, it might or it might not implement the repository pattern, depending if the domain objects are used 'as is' by EF. As a personal opinion, EF should never be considered a repository since it exposes querying details defeating the repository's purpose and it only works with a rdbms. EF is about abstracting sql/tables, Repository is about abstracting **all persistence**

Comment: in this particular case we are talking exactly about SQL persistence. EF is an abstraction over database. Mike, I want to ask you why exactly do you need repository pattern?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know enough yet to tell you whether I need a repository pattern or not.  Right now I'm just working through examples and tutorials and ran into this issue.

Comment: @Mike The majority are bad tutorials including the code above. Repository is not a recipe or a tool that you must use, it's just a principle. You should know when and why and then you can write the code (your own implementation) yourself, because the implementation depends on the app. What you have here is just a bunch of classes named Repository

Comment: Well, I have a bunch of tables that may need to capture some information on insert, and some that would all be inserted together as a group.  I can do all of that easy enough in my controller code without repository classes or unit of work, but I thought the goal was to have controller independent of database specific operations like that.  Obviously I'm misunderstanding all of it.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand this better after some time, so figured I would close it.  I didn't need to "override" anything, I just needed to add the additional work in my unit of work class (duh), and then call the insert.  Thanks for the thought provoking responses.